# How to format json result returned by spring boot

Tags: json, api

My spring boot program (`http://localhost:8080/api/cutomers`) return the json file as :

```
[
    {
        id: 1,
        address: "Super Mart of the West",
        state: "Arkansas",
        companyName: "Bentonville",
        zipcode: "72716",
        city: "702 SW 8th Street",
        phone: "(800) 555-2171",
        fax: "(800) 555-2797"
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        address: "Electronics Depot",
        state: "Georgia",
        companyName: "Atlanta",
        zipcode: "30339",
        city: "2455 Paces Ferry Road NW",
        phone: "(800) 595-3231",
        fax: "(800) 595-3232"
    },{
        id: 3, 
        address: "Screen Shop",
        state: "North Carolina",
        companyName: "Mooresville",
        zipcode: "28117",
        city: "1000 Lowes Blvd",
        phone: "(800) 445-6938",
        fax: "(800) 445-6937"
    }
]
```

To expose this data into devextreme gx-grid, I want to have this format of json :

```
{
    totalCount: 3,
    items: [
        {
            id: 1,
            address: "Super Mart of the West",
            state: "Arkansas",
            companyName: "Bentonville",
            zipcode: "72716",
            city: "702 SW 8th Street",
            phone: "(800) 555-2171",
            fax: "(800) 555-2797"
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            address: "Electronics Depot",
            state: "Georgia",
            companyName: "Atlanta",
            zipcode: "30339",
            city: "2455 Paces Ferry Road NW",
            phone: "(800) 595-3231",
            fax: "(800) 595-3232"
        },{
            id: 3,
            address: "Screen Shop",
            state: "North Carolina",
            companyName: "Mooresville",
            zipcode: "28117",
            city: "1000 Lowes Blvd",
            phone: "(800) 445-6938",
            fax: "(800) 445-6937"
        }
    ]
}
```

How can I do that please ?

Answer (score 0):

You can create an parent DTO which contains item array  and count properties.
 return the parent DTO as response.
Spring Rest controller will take care of displaying in that format

Comment: Thank your Kumar.

Comment: Can you ytel me how can I do that ?